# How do I create a view with filter on a field built using the date module?

Tags: views, datetime

I created a content type that includes a [date](http://drupal.org/project/date) field.  I want to create a view that filters on this field, but it appears that the field is being seen as a text field because there are no operators for greater than or less than like I would see if I were filtering on the posted date.  I only see text based operators like length, starts with, etc.  What do I need to do?  I'm running Drupal 7.  How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 types of date filter handlers in Views ; try not to use the one that is your field but **the date field, that will ask you on which date field it'll filter**.

Comment: Thank you.  I finally found what you were talking about after I enabled the Date views piece of the Dates module.

Answer (score 0):

Just to better explain how to have date support on views: it has to be enabled "date views" module.

People using drush just needs to execute:

```
drush en date_views
```